# Android variables retaining values after uninstalling the app

Tags: android, variables, save, registry

I need a way to be able to tell if a user has uninstalled and reinstalled the android application. I use shared preferences for when the user CLOSES the app, however, I need to save out a variable that will let me know if the user has ever opened the app on this device in the past.

(Basically the user is awarded items in the game when first starting the game, after they are used the player could essentially just uninstall and reinstall and use the items again) I need a variable that gets saved in the android registry that will tell me if the player has ever opened the app before (even if they have previously uninstalled).

Is this possible?

Comment: then you need to save it on external memory which is not assured it wont be deleted, so your save bet is on the cloud..

Comment: you need to identify the devices/players individually and code a combination of the same with the server, a server independent code may not be able to meet your requirement. You can store a db or file on the device, but the user can delete that also

Comment: I would recommend keeping a table of seen devices on a server. Anything local to the phone can be removed/modified.